# Confirm Java ArrayList contains a specific value

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I have a "bank" program, with the following chunk of code:

```
private void doPayment(JTextField accountNumField, JTextField paymentField)
    {
        int accountNum = Integer.parseInt(accountNumField.getText());
        double paymentAmt = Double.parseDouble(paymentField.getText());
        String paymentProcessed = "-RECEIPT OF PAYMENT-" + "\n\n" + "Account Number:" + " " + accountObject.getAccountNum() + "Beginning Balance:" + " " + accountObject.getBegBalance() 
        + "Payment Amount:" + " " + accountObject.getPaymentAmount() + "Ending Balance:" + " " + accountObject.getEndBalance();
        String errorMsg = "ERROR: ACCOUNT NUMBER" + " " + "[" + accountObject.getAccountNum() + "]" + " " + "NOT FOUND. PLEASE VERIFY THAT THE ACCOUNT INFORMATION IS VALID AND CORRECT.";

        if (accountsArrayList.contains(accountNum))
        {
            accountObject.transactionTwo(paymentAmt);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, paymentProcessed, "PAYMENT PROCESSED SUCCESSFULLY", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMsg, "INVALID ACCOUNT ERROR", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);          
        }

    }
```

In theory, after the user creates the account for the client, he/she navigates to a "Process Payment" window and enters two things: `accountNum` and `paymentAmt` then hits submit, at which point the `doPayment` method is called.

This method is supposed to work such that the program iterates through the `accountsArrayList` which contains THREE items: `lastName, firstName, and accountNum`. If it finds that the `accountNum` provided matches a prexisting `accountNum` in the arrayList, then the transaction is processed accordingly. If no matching `accountNum` can be found then it returns an error message.

At present, it just returns the error message in the `else` part of the `if-else`. I thought that the `contains(item)` method automatically iterates through the Arraylist. If that isn't the case, do I need an enhanced FOR-loop?

Comment: accountsArrayList.contains(accountNum) will return true only, if it contains integers sinve accountNum is an int. Is it of type ArrayList<Integer>?

Comment: @mayamar No. My arraylist is of type ArrayList<Account> as it contains a list of account objects that have a lastName, firstName, and accountNum associated with them.

Comment: @mre I will, but isn't that the opposite of what I want to do?

Comment: The contains()-method looks for the content of the array. You can ask accountsArrayList.contains(createAccountOf(lastName, firstName, accountNum)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (accountsArrayList.contains(accountNum))
```

**accountsArrayList** is a ArrayList which contains Objects of type Account.

**contains** returns true only if accountsArrayList contains an Object type **Account** given as argument. In your code, **accountNum** is a **int**
so the compiler reads it like `if(Account == INTEGER)`

You have to go throw each Account in your ArrayList and get it's accountNum and than compare the values.

```
for(int i = 0; i < accountsArrayList.size; i++){
   if(accountsArrayList.get(i).accountNum == accountNum){
     //success
   }
   else {
     //error
   }
}
```

Comment: add an explanation to your answer. Just a piece of code wont help much the future users.

Comment: Oh my gosh it works! You are brilliant! Haha. Thanks so much!